# Screen movement when I click input field

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```css
.input--custom {
  border: 0.1px solid #cfd7fd;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  /* set a fixed width in pixels */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* include border and padding in total width */
  word-break: break-word;
  /* allow long words to break and wrap to next line */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* hide any overflow */
  ;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.input--width {
  height: 100px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.chatbox textarea {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.conversation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;

}

.conversation .operator-response {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  color: #333;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 80%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right:auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;

}

.conversation .user-input {
  /* background-color: #f4f6ff; */
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 80%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left:auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  align-self: flex-end; /* added */

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<Modal visible={visible} onCancel={onClose} centered footer={null} // title={title} bodyStyle={{ height: "70vh", overflowY: "auto", margin: "0", padding: "0" }}>

  <div style={{overflow: 'auto', height: '60vh'}}>

    <div ref={conversationContainerRef}>

      <div key={index} class="conversation">

        <div class="operator-response">Hi. How can i change settings</div>
        <div class="user-input">Go to settings page </div>

      </div>
      <div style={{display: "flex"}} class="conversation">
        <div class="operator-response">Hello how are you</div>


      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class='flexrow'>
    <textarea onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Type your message here and click submit" class="input--custom input--width "></textarea>
    <img onClick={handleSubmit} class="sendButton" style={{width: "20px", paddingLeft: "20px"}} src={sendIcon}></img>
  </div>

</Modal>
```

I have a modal like this with an input component at the bottom. When I click the input component for typing, screen-automatically focus on the input components(Zooms in.) As a result I have drag and adjust the position again to see the send button.

Is there any way Modal can remain in the same position without any movement?

Before clicking this is how it looks
[image]

After clicking input field this is how it changes[image]

What attribute needs to be changed to avoid the moment? Do you need any other information?

Comment: It would be great if you had a minimal reproducible example. We cannot see your broader project, nor the CSS styles that may be in play here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior on most mobile browsers is to zoom if the font-size of the element is less than 16px.

In your case, you could add a `font-size:16px` to your `.input--custom` class to solve this problem. Here is a working demo on Codepen (to test it on your mobile device easily):
https://codepen.io/atalaykutlay/pen/vYzapNJ

```css
.input--custom {
      border: 0.1px solid #cfd7fd;
      padding: 15px;
      display: block;
      height: 100px;
      font-size:16px;
      width: 100%;
      /* set a fixed width in pixels */
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /* include border and padding in total width */
      word-break: break-word;
      /* allow long words to break and wrap to next line */
      overflow: hidden;
      /* hide any overflow */
      ;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    }

    .input--width {
      height: 100px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

    textarea::placeholder {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    }

    .chatbox textarea {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    textarea:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    .conversation {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: flex-start;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px;

    }

    .conversation .operator-response {
      background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
      color: #333;
      padding: 15px 18px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      max-width: 80%;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: left;
      margin-right:auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      clear: both;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;

    }

    .conversation .user-input {
      /* background-color: #f4f6ff; */
      background-color: #000;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 18px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      max-width: 80%;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: right;
      margin-left:auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      clear: both;
      align-self: flex-end; /* added */

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


    <Modal visible={visible} onCancel={onClose} centered footer={null} // title={title} bodyStyle={{ height: "70vh", overflowY: "auto", margin: "0", padding: "0" }}>

      <div style={{overflow: 'auto', height: '60vh'}}>

        <div ref={conversationContainerRef}>

          <div key={index} class="conversation">

            <div class="operator-response">Hi. How can i change settings</div>
            <div class="user-input">Go to settings page </div>

          </div>
          <div style={{display: "flex"}} class="conversation">
            <div class="operator-response">Hello how are you</div>


          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class='flexrow'>
        <textarea onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Type your message here and click submit" class="input--custom input--width "></textarea>
        <img onClick={handleSubmit} class="sendButton" style={{width: "20px", paddingLeft: "20px"}} src={sendIcon}></img>
      </div>

    </Modal>
```

Additionally, you could simply deactivate all zooming using the meta tag below, however iOs devices will keep zooming into the input fields as long as the font-size of the element is less than 16px.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```